# How to modify every third element in matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I had to make a matrix using numpy.array method. How can I now update every third element of my matrix? I have made a for loop for the problem but that is not the optimal solution. Is there a way to avoid loops? For example if I have this matrix:

```
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                  [5,6,7,8],
                  [4,7,6,9]])
```

is there a way to add 1 to every third element and get this matrix:

```
[[2,2,3,5],[5,6,8,8],[4,8,6,9]]
```

Comment: `matrix.ravel()[::3] += 1` if no copy occurs when call `ravel`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
matrix = np.ascontiguousarray(matrix)
matrix.ravel()[::3] += 1
```

Why does the [ascontiguousarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) is needed? Because `matrix` may not be c-contiguous (for example `matrix` may have fortran-order - column major). It that case [ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) returns a copy instead of a view so a simple inplace operation `matrix.ravel()[::3] += 1` will not work as expected.

**Example 1**

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 7, 6, 9]])

arr.ravel()[::3] += 1
print(arr)
```

Works as expected:

```
[[2 2 3 5]
 [5 6 8 8]
 [4 8 6 9]]
```

**Example 2**

But with fortran-order

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 7, 6, 9]])

arr = np.asfortranarray(arr)
arr.ravel()[::3] += 1
print(arr)
```

produces:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]
 [4 7 6 9]]
```

**Example 3**

Will work as expected in both cases

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 7, 6, 9]])
# arr = np.asfortranarray(arr)

arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
arr.ravel()[::3] += 1
print(arr)
```